# Rows to columns - sql 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just learning SQL - I have the following table:

```
Site1   Totals 
Status1 20 
Status2 5 
Status3 15 
Status4 145 
Status5 1
```

And need to convert the columns and rows, adding a new column name "Server Name" and changing the rows to columns, to return the following:

```
Server name   Status1  Status2  Status3 Status4 Status5
Site1            20      5        15      145      1
```

Is anyone able to help with this?

Thankyou

Comment: `PIVOT` does this. If there are an unknown number of possible Status values search this site for *dynamic pivot*.

Comment: Are Site1 and Totals your column headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ServerName = 'Site1', *
from
(
  select Totals, Site1
  from Sometable
) d
pivot
(
  max(Totals)
  for Site1 in (Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4, Status5)
) piv;
```

**EDIT**:
If you need to dynamically load values from Site1 column you can do it this way:

```
CREATE table #yourtable
    ([Site1] varchar(20), [Totals] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO #yourtable
    ([Site1], [Totals])
VALUES
    ('Status1', 20),
    ('Status2', 45),
    ('Status3', 77),
    ('Status4', 55)
;


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Site1) 
                    from #yourtable
                    group by Site1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ServerName=''Site1'', ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select Site1, Totals
                from #yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Totals)
                for Site1 in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/626131/sql-simple-pivot-example)

Comment: Perfect :)  Thanks